# Reloading view after applying scale transform breaks frame of the UIScrollView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using [SpreadsheetView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView) and trying to zoom into it using a pinch gesture and a scale transform. The view zooms fine but when I try to reload the data after it has been zoomed out, the frame of the view is much smaller than it should be. This is the snippet of code that handles the zooming of the view -

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        lastScale = Float(recognizer.scale)
    }
    if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {
        currentScale = recognizer.view?.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.scale") as! Float

        var newScale = 1 - (lastScale - Float(recognizer.scale))
        newScale = min(newScale, SpreadsheetViewController.kMaxScale / currentScale)
        newScale = max(newScale, SpreadsheetViewController.kMinScale / currentScale)
        spreadsheetView.transform = spreadsheetView.transform.scaledBy(x: CGFloat(newScale), y: CGFloat(newScale))
        lastScale = Float(recognizer.scale)
    }
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        spreadsheetView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topView.frame.maxY, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - topView.frame.maxY)
        print(spreadsheetView.frame.size.width)
        print(spreadsheetView.scrollView.frame.size.width)
    }
}
```

I am explicitly setting the frame of the `spreadsheetView` to cover the frame of the `UIViewController` after the pinch gesture has ended and it manages to stick to that frame after reloading but I think its the frame of the `UIScrollView` inside the `SpreadsheetView` that loses its frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpreadsheetView` seems to use its `frame` size properties to draw its content. Modifying the `transform` will change the `frame` values accordingly, and so using these (instead of the `bounds` sizes) will make the end result wrong, in your case effectively scaling down twice. This is likely a miss in the `SpreadsheetView`.

You can work around it by using a container for the `SpreadsheetView`. Create a regular `UIView` to do the transforms on, and embed the `SpreadsheetView` as a child, without any transforms.

I did a quick test on one of the demo apps included with the `SpreadsheetView`, and it confirms my thoughts. Doing a simple transform directly on the `SpreadsheetView` with scale 0.5, 0.5, and set the background color to red, results in this picture. Note that the red background is visible, which it shouldn't.

[image]

The same test using a `UIView` as a container for the `SpreadsheetView`, scaling the container to 0.5, 0.5, and setting the container's background to red, results in this picture. Works as intended.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @LGP. That worked for me after being stuck for days

Comment: Forgot to award the bounty. Did it just now