# Zooming out the table in ScrollView while keeping the frame unchanged

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using the [SwiftDataTables](https://github.com/pavankataria/SwiftDataTables) package to represent my tables. That table I pack into another view (aka viewTable), which is in turn added to the scroll view. 
The idea is to zoom out and see more of the table. Ideally, I would have `scrollView.zoomScale = 0.4` as a default value. However, zooming out only results in a smaller rectangle of the view and the table in it.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is very similar to [that question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739735/reloading-view-after-applying-scale-transform-breaks-frame-of-the-uiscrollview-i), only using scrollView's built-in zooming.
Yet, when I use

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {...}
```

it seems to have no influence.
I have tried to change

`scrollView.contentSize` and `scrollView.contentOffset`; `viewTable.frame`,`viewTable.bounds`, `anchor.contraint(equalTo: scrollView....)`
etc.

The view always gets smaller, not filling the scroll view

Another thought was to use `viewTable.transform`, but it seems the constraints are still applied to the unchanged view, thus resulting in the same smaller rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
It was easier to fork the SwiftDataTables and add some functionality (change font) so that the table was "zoomed out" at the beginning with scrollView.zoomScale = 1.